# App crash due to empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, nsarray

```
NSString *strMethod;
NSString *strType = @"restaurant";
NSDictionary *params = @{@"type": strType};
NSString *strMethod = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", API_CATEGORY_SHOP, @"en"];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
 manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
 NSMutableSet *contentTypes = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithSet:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/json"]];
 [contentTypes addObject:@"text/html"];
 [contentTypes addObject:@"application/json"];

 manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = contentTypes;
 [manager POST:strMethod parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id response){

    if ([[response objectForKey:@"result"] intValue] == 1) {

        [_arrRestaurtentTypeList removeAllObjects];
        [_arrRestaurtentTypeList addObjectsFromArray:[response objectForKey:@"Main Category"]];

        NSDictionary *dictAll = [_arrRestaurtentTypeList lastObject];

        if (dictAll) {
            [_arrRestaurtentTypeList removeLastObject];
            [_arrRestaurtentTypeList insertObject:dictAll atIndex:0];
        }

        [_collRestaurentTypeList reloadData];
        [_tblRestaurent reloadData];

    }

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    ;
}];
}
```

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182caa364 0x181ef0528 0x182c42e9c 0x182b72820 0x100858628 0x100857624 0x18c279670 0x18c279bdc 0x18c31ee74 0x18c3e58b0 0x18c371910 0x18c4b5c98 0x18c299240 0x18c298bb4 0x18c2988c0 0x18c298960 0x186cfce14 0x1010a528c 0x1010a9ea0 0x182c52544 0x182c50120 0x182b6fe58 0x184a1cf84 0x18c2c467c 0x10085e320 0x18268c56c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: how your response comes ?

Comment: show us the code where you are getting crash. In collectionview method ?

Comment: where are you allocated *arrRestaurtentTypeList* and are you sure you get data in *[response objectForKey:@"Main Category"]* as you get what error is it self answer you just need to check why that array are empty. most case that coz of you did not initialize

Comment: i initialised it in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([[response objectForKey:@"result"] intValue] == 1) {

    [_arrRestaurtentTypeList removeAllObjects];
    [_arrRestaurtentTypeList addObjectsFromArray:[response objectForKey:@"Main Category"]];

    NSDictionary *dictAll = [_arrRestaurtentTypeList lastObject];

    if (dictAll) {
        [_arrRestaurtentTypeList removeLastObject];
        [_arrRestaurtentTypeList insertObject:dictAll atIndex:0];
    }

    [_collRestaurentTypeList reloadData];
    [_tblRestaurent reloadData];

}
```

change this line with below code

```
 if ([[response valueForKey:@"result"] count] >0){
for (NSDictionary *dict in [response valueForKey:@"result"]) {
                        NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                        [newDict addEntriesFromDictionary:dict];
                        [_arrRestaurtentTypeList addObject:newDict];
                    }
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [_tblRestaurent reloadData];

                    });
```

Comment: I added break point it goes to the didSelected method of collectionview

Comment: now see edit and let me know if it works & thnx Karthik

Comment: this problem occurs when network connection not get properly